# One liner foreach in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following function in my PHP code:

```
function getFromTable(){ //$sql,$index,$index2,...,$pdo

  $args = func_get_args(); // because we don't know how many $index arguments there will be
  $sql = $args[0];
  $indexes = [];
  for ($i=1; $i <count($args)-1; $i++) {
    array_push($indexes,$args[$i]);
  }
  $pdo = $args[count($args)-1]; //penultimate index
  $ret = [];

  $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result->execute();

  foreach($result as $row){
    array_push($ret,[$row[$indexes]);
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

The purpose of the function is to return rows from a MySQL query. User can choose which indexes to return. Since I don't know the number of indexes, I use the func_get_args() argument. First argument is always the query, last argument is PDO, and all the arguments in-between are indexes. The problem arises in the foreach statement, where I push the values of the indexes into an array. I want all indexes to be in one array, however I don't know how to do it in PHP. If it was Python, I would use a one liner for loop or lambda. What are the alternatives in PHP?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What **exactly** is not working with the given code?

Comment: @NicoHaase I believe i explained everything in the last paragraph. I want to ```array_push($ret,``` and then every index given in the argument, however, I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: Inside the loop over all rows, just loop over `$indexes` again, and pick the columns with the corresponding indices from $row. Add all those to a temporary array, and then add that temporary array to your overall result array afterwards …?

Comment: @CBroe oh I didn't think of that. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly let's take advantage of PHP 7.4 features like argument unpacking and short-form lambdas:

```
function getFromTable($sql, ...$indices) {
  $pdo = array_pop($indices); // Pop the last array entry
  $flippedIndices = array_flip($indices); // This is important
  $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result->execute();
  return array_map(fn ($row) => array_intersect_key($row, $flippedIndices), $result);
}
```

Here's the breakdown:

1. We write the parameters as `$sql, ...$indices` so we now say that the first argument is the query and the rest of the arguments are indices. It would actually work nicer if the parameters were `$sql, $pdo, ...$indices` to save us from needing (2)
2. We pop `$pdo` from the rest arguments since it's last argument.
3. The way to get specific indices from an array is with `array_intersect_key` but to use this we need to pass an array with the keys we want to intersect. `array_flip` will achive this.
4. The `array_map` should map all rows to arrays which only have the specified keys.  We use the PHP 7.4+ arrow functions feature but you can just use `function ($row) use ($flippedIndices) { return array_intersect_key($row, $flippedIndices); }` for the same result if you want to use this code in earlier PHP versions

[Sandbox link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bfd23076432a5d8a20a98861e1f23ca5a52ec53)

Comment: If you are doing a rewrite, wouldn't it make more sense to pass the 2, must have, parameter as param 1 and 2 so `function getFromTable($pdo, $sql, ...$indices) {`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I mentioned that as an option, but I was concerned that changing the 
argument order might break code that already uses this function. Given the state of the function maybe this was me being overly cautious